# How to create a query to get table from multiple columns

Tags: mysql

I am creating a table of all the users listing their username and pending questions with total number of allotted question.

I have 2 tables
first one contain the username,initial question number and final question number columns and second table contain the timestamp username and submitted question number

**first db table**

| username | first que | last que |
| --- | --- | --- |
| usera | 101 | 200 |
| userb | 201 | 300 |
| userc | 301 | 400 |

**second db table**

| username | submitted question number | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| usera | 103 | 13-06-2022 |
| usera | 102 | 11-06-2022 |
| userb | 201 | 12-06-2022 |
| usera | 101 | 09-06-2022 |

so i want to output it as a username,total question allotted, pending question

**Output i want on webpage**

| username | total question allotted | pending question |
| --- | --- | --- |
| usera | 99 | 96 |
| userb | 99 | 98 |
| usera | 99 | 99 |

total pending question must be calculated as by (total questions in series - total submitted questions)

Comment: 200 - 101 = 99, how do you arrive at 100 allotted questions?

Comment: @Stu oh sorry, i just missed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can done this using next query:

```
SELECT 
    first_table.username, 
    (last_que-first_que) total_questions_allotted,
    (last_que-first_que-answers) pending_questions
FROM first_table 
JOIN (
    SELECT username, COUNT(*) answers FROM second_table GROUP BY username
) second_table_groupped USING(username);
```

or using next PHP code:

```
<?php
$query = 'SELECT 
    first_table.username, 
    (last_que-first_que) total_questions_allotted,
    (last_que-first_que-answers) pending_questions
FROM first_table 
JOIN (
    SELECT username, COUNT(*) answers FROM second_table GROUP BY username
) second_table_groupped USING(username)';


$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$data = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

print_r($data);
```

[run PHP online](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/2ff1761195912ec5518cf7e991b31ec3/php/php81/6379170a4eac53b089032321aadafffc/)

Comment: sir there is problem as user may have many question number from another question set. so i want only to count pending questions between the currect range from last que to first que, all other questions number expert that series must be excluded.

Comment: @RohanVerma , Please look this version https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/9efecc1eb9fc372d6de681b029aa6286/php/php81/2215b2333a7fabb8f94a1bd3ed4ce0b9/